# Is there a Firefox add-on to use vim to edit textboxes?

Tags: firefox, vim

or "How do I answer questions on SO in Firefox using gVim inside the textboxes?"

Comment: as of Firefox 57 (and after) the vast majority (if not all) of the current answers are outdated, unfortunately.

Comment: wasavi suggested by Andrea, works fine, I've just tested it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125)

From the extension page:

> At the bottom right corner of any edit
>   box, a little edit button will appear.
>   Click it. If this is the first time
>   you've used "It's All Text!" then you
>   will be asked to set your preferences,
>   most importantly the editor.
>
> The web page will pop up in your
>   selected editor. When you save it,
>   it'll refresh in the web page. Wait
>   for the magic yellow glow that means
>   that the radiation has taken effect!

Comment: A word of caution for others: After setting the editor to gVim on WinXP I got an "Unable to open editor" error which stumped me for a while. Turns out that you need to restart Firefox each time you make a change to your editor!

That said, this comment was written in "It's all text"! Thanks SO!
:wq

Comment: If this is still a problem, please report it at http://trac.gerf.org/itsalltext -- Thanks!

Comment: Changes to the FF plugin architecture, which we've been warned about for a year, and finally implemented in 57, means that It's All Text is dead. The developer recommends "emacs chrome" or "GhostText" neither of which is a compelling replacement. Vimperator is dead, too, for the same reason.

Comment: And GhostText seems to work only for Linux not Windows (or at least, I gave up after I found it requires tcl shell and some other libraries...).

Comment: On linux, textern https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textern/ seems to offer the same function.

Answer (score 23):

[Vimperator](http://vimperator.mozdev.org/) makes Firefox act very much like VIM:

> Vimperator is a free browser add-on for Firefox, which makes it look and behave like the Vim text editor. It has similar key bindings, and you could call it a modal web browser, as key bindings differ according to which mode you are in.

Once you have the cursor in a text box, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to open in your editor, which defaults to gvim.

Comment: Vimperator is awesome! Thank you. "It's all text" answers the question more directly though.

Comment: NOTE: Vimperator will stop functioning with Firefox 57!

Comment: Not supported anymore.

Comment: For a similar solution that works today, you can use Tridactyl, as per my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411545/1196465

Answer (score 20):

The current answers don't work anymore now that Mozilla removed XUL in favour of WebExtensions. With recent firefox versions, there are the following options (sorted in descending order by the current popularity on addons.mozilla.org).

[GhostText](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghosttext/) provides instant synchronization between editor and textbox via editor-specific plugins. The project is on [github](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText) and the [vim extension](https://github.com/falstro/ghost-text-vim) is written in Tcl.

[withExEditor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/withexeditor/) is cross-platform but requires a native application written in node.js. In addition to editing text fields it also allows viewing the source of the page, MathML, SVG and the current selection. The project on [github](https://github.com/asamuzaK/withExEditor) and the [native node.js application](https://github.com/asamuzaK/withExEditorHost)

[Textern](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textern/) requires a (currently) Linux-only native application written in Python. Synchronizes the content of the text field while you type in the editor. The extension and the native app can be found on [github](https://github.com/jlebon/textern)

Comment: I know the question mentions vim, but it's worth noting that for GhostText: sublime, vscode, and atom are the only other editors supported; no emacs :(

Answer (score 9):

[Tridactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tridactyl-vim/) is probably what you're looking for nowadays.

It's the spiritual successor to the likes of Pentadactyl and Vimperator, which are not available for the current version of Firefox.

If you want something more like It's All Text, where the editing area appears right on top of the browser text area rather than launching an editor window, and you're willing to use Neovim, check out [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim).

Answer (score 6):

[ViewSourceWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/394) is another addon worth lookng at.  It supports more than just edit boxes and text.  For example, you can configure it to open images in the GIMP.

Another feature that I find useful is that it can pop-up a dialog box that shows all the js and css scripts used on the page.  You can then choose to view/edit file in your preferred editor.

For answering questions on SO, you may also want to get the [Vim Markdown Syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242)

Answer (score 5):

[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) will let you use whatever editor you want. To use vim with it, you'll need a small shell script to open it in a terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec xterm -e /usr/bin/vim "$@"
```

If you have GVim, you won't need the shell, script, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

The "It's all Text" extension, perhaps?

http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125

Answer (score 3):

If you use [vimperator](http://vimperator.mozdev.org/) and have the [markdown syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242) installed, a useful line for your .vimperatorrc is:

```
au LocationChange .* :set editor="gvim -f"
au LocationChange stackoverflow\.com :set editor="gvim -f -c 'set ft=mkd'"
```

This will tell vim to do syntax highlighting for markdown when you are on stackoverflow.com, but not when you are any other site. There are similar hacks for wikipedia/mediawiki etc. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the [vimperator](http://vimperator.mozdev.org/) extension - of course, that does a *lot* more than what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing it is experimental, but the [jV extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8529) looks good. To quote from the page:

*This extension makes all html textareas into a very stripped-down version of Vi[m]. It's modal, supports infinite undo, has register support, search, visual mode, and various movement and editing commands.*

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental way to directly embed the real vim in firefox using [embedded editor](http://people.ksp.sk/~martin/firefox/extensions/EmbeddedEditor/) - though it requires mozplugger and will only work on Linux.

Comment: That sounds really useful, but the link is broken and I can't figure out how to search for it.  Do you have any more information?  Perhaps the name of the add-on?  Or is it dead forever?

Comment: @D.W. It was called embedded editor. I've found another link via google and updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

When using Vimperator in Windows (I am using Vista) you may need to double-escape the path to gvim.exe to use it as the external editor. Single escaping did not work for me as Vimperator unescapes it twice. Eg:

```
:set editor="C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\ (x86)\\\\Vim\\\\vim72\\\\gvim.exe" -f
```

Then while in a text box you use Ctrl+I and it will open gvim for editing. When you save and exit it will update the text box.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the wasavi extension. You might want to check out the all versions page to make sure you try out the latest version. (Copy of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/527895/edit-text-areas-using-vi-key-bindings-inside-the-textbox-in-firefox-without-o/615678#615678).)

Comment: Not anymore among the Firefox add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [ViewSourceWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/394) addon to achieve the same. Just right-click on any text input and you can edit it using Vim.

Answer (score 1):

As said by others,
as a Vi/(g)Vim user you'll probably want to look at the Vimperator addon, which also provides the what you ask: 
inside a textbox, hit <C-i> to launch the external editor.
(can be defined in _vimperatorrc: set editor=gvim -f )

Answer (score 1):

A hint for Mac users: if you want to use "It's all text" with vim, the easiest way is to use http://code.google.com/p/macvim/ . Point "It's all text" to the mvim script that's provided along with the .app (you can place this script anywhere, I choose /usr/bin/ so that I can load mvim from the command line)

Answer (score 1):

[Pterosaur](https://github.com/ardagnir/pterosaur) is a Firefox plugin that allows you to use Vim in all input fields. It uses an actual Vim process in the background so it has all the functionality you expect, including reading your .vimrc configuration and your plugins.

Comment: It's been unmaintained for a year and seems to be broken in modern Firefox (at least, I couldn't get it to work). I'd suggest wasavi instead.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox-57 on Linux, I installed textern https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textern/, and found it to be a suitable replacement for ViewSourceWith for editing text boxes.